# error messages when writing Mex files, problem with array output from functions?

Tags: matlab, openmp, mex

I am more of a Matlab programmer, and have not used C in years! Now I have to write some code in C and have it called from Matlab via the mexFunction command. So far so good. But my code requires many function calls where both the argument and the return values are arrays. For this I am using pointer returns. But I have run into about a million difficulties, once one is fixed another is created.

example of the sort code is as follows (the actual code is massive)

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "math.h"

int Slength=95;


double innercfunction(double q,double y)
{
  int i;
  double X;

  X=q*y;

}

double *c1function(double q,double Sim[])
{
  double *F12=malloc(Slength);
  int i;
  double vdummy,qdummy;
  qdummy=q;

  for(i=0;i<Slength;i++)
  {
    vdummy=Sim[i];
    F12[i]=innercfunction(qdummy,vdummy);
  }
  return F12;
}


void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *prhs[],int nrhs,const mxArray *plhs[])
{
  double *q=mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
  double *Sim=mxGetPr(prhs[1]);

  double *SS=c1function(q,Sim);
}
```

i save it as help_file.c and compile from THE MATLAB workspace as:

```
mex -g help_file.c
```

to which i get the following error:

```
help_file.c: In function ‘mexFunction’:
help_file.c:38: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘c1function’
help_file.c:17: note: expected ‘double’ but argument is of type ‘double *’
```

i tried initially passing Sim[i] instead of vdummy, that did not work which is why I defined the dummy variable in the first place.

I imagine this is a trivial problem, but I would still appreciate peoples help on this.

Answer (score 3):

The prototype of `clfunction` requires you to pass a scalar double as the first argument; you're passing a pointer-to-double `q`, hence the compiler error. Are you expecting `prhs[0]` to contain a scalar? If so, you could use `q[0]` to extract the value; or else, you could use `mxGetScalar(prhs[0])` which returns a scalar-double ( http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/apiref/mxgetscalar.html ).

However, I'm not sure that fixing that would make your mex file work as expected. I would suggest taking some time to read the mex examples here: http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html

In particular, your current mex file isn't going to produce any output arguments since you aren't assigning to the left-hand side `plhs`.